# Retrieve values from 2 different tables and put them in a view with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I have 2 table as **Food**:

- Food_id(pk)
- Foodname
- Description
- Image
- Price

Ans other table is **Restaurant**:

- Res_id(pk)
- ResName
- Location

I make Pivot table **food_restaurant** as:

- id
- Food_id(fk)
- Res_id(fk)

I want to show Location of Restaurant along with food details in my view.For that I make function in model **Food.php** as

```
public function restaurant()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Restaurant','food_restaurant','Food_id','Res_id');

}
```

And other model **Restaurant.php** as

```
public function food()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Food','food_restaurant','Res_id','Food_id');
}
```

My **Controller** is:

```
class Detailscontroller extends Controller

      {
       public function index()

       {

       $Foods= Food::all();

       return view('welcome', compact('Foods'));

       }
      public function show($Food_id)

       {
   $food =Food::findOrFail($Food_id);

       return view('show', compact('food'));

       }

       }
```

And Routes are:

```
Route::get('/','DetailsController@index');

Route::get('/{Food_id}', 'DetailsController@show');
```

View **welcome.blade.php** is:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

     @section('content')

     <div class="container">

      <div class="row">

       <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">

      @foreach($Foods as $Food)

    <p><img src="{{ asset('uploads/'.$Food->Image) }}" /><p>
     <Food>

     <h2>
      <a  href="/{{$Food->Food_id}}">{{$Food->FoodName}}
     <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i></a
      </h2>
      </Food>

      @endforeach            

            </div>          
      </div>

        @endsection
```

And **show.blade.php** is:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

<h1 align="center">{{$food -> FoodName}}</h1>

<p><img src="{{ asset('uploads/'.$food->Image) }}" /><p>

 <detail>
 <h3><p>FoodDescription:</h3><h4>{{$food->Description}}</h4></p>

 <h3><p>Price:</h3><h4>{{$food->Price}}</h4></p>

 @foreach ($food->restaurant as $restaurant) 

 <h3><p>Location:</h3><h4>{{$restaurant->Location}}</p></h4>

 @endforeach 

 @endsection
```

But it does not show Location to me.How can I show Location in my show.blade.php view?I am new to laravel.Where is the problem?

Comment: Try changing your show method in your controller to this : ```$food =Food::with('restaurant')->findOrFail($Food_id);```

Comment: No,it not works.Giving error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::restaur‌​ant()".

Comment: did you check whether you are getting restaurant relation by using dd($food->restaurant) in your view

Comment: Do you have the proper namespace and use in your models? Assuming your namespace is just "App" do you have ```use App\Restaurant;``` defined in Food.php and ```use App\Food;``` defined in Restaurant.php?

Comment: @Landjea No,i have not added these namespaces.Now I added these and it works :) Thanx a lot.

Answer (score 0):

return the food array to the view with associated restaurant.

```
public function show($Food_id)
{
   $food = Food::with('restaurant')->findOrFail($Food_id);
   return view('show', compact('food'));
}
```

Comment: No,it not works.Giving error "Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\‌​Query\Builder::restau‌​r‌​ant()".

Comment: I want to add "Category" relationship with foods.can I use  '$food = Food::with('restaurant','category')->findOrFail($Food_id);'