# Show data from multiple tables in view laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I asked question whose link is:
[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38955118/retrieve-values-from-2-different-tables-and-put-them-in-a-view-with-laravel)

Now my problem is that I want to show "CategoryName' of in food details.For that I add function in Categories.php model as:

```
 public function food()
{
return $this->hasMany('App\Food','food_categories','Category_id','Food_id');
}
```

and in food.php

```
public function restaurant()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Restaurant','food_restaurant','Food_id','Res_id');       
}

public function categories()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Categories','food_categories');
}
```

Then in show.blade.php I add:

```
@foreach ($food->restaurant as $restaurant) 

<h3><p>RestaurantName:</h3><h4>{{$restaurant->ResName}}</p></h4>
<h3><p>Contact #:</h3><h4>{{$restaurant->Contact}}</p></h4>
<h3><p>Location:</h3><h4>{{$restaurant->Address_Loc}}</p></h4>

@endforeach 


@foreach ($food->categories as $categories) 

<h3><p>CategoryName:</h3><h4>{{$categories->CategoryName}}</p></h4>

@endforeach
```

And I changed controller to :

```
public function show($Food_id)
{
$food = Food::with('restaurant.categories')->findOrFail($Food_id);
return view('show', compact('food'));
}
```

But it does not shows me categoryname.Plz help me where is the problem?

Comment: Do you have the `CategoryName` column in `Categories` table?

Comment: Yes I have categories table having "Categoryid,CategoryName" columns.

Comment: Should't it be $food->restaurant ? and a restaurant having categories? (Checked with the previous question) I can't see the Food model having categories...

Comment: I added categories in food model as shown above in food.php

Comment: My bad, have you tried `@foreach ($food->categories() as $categories) `? Like calling the method?

Comment: Can we use this "$food = Food::with('restaurant.categories')->findOrFail($Food_id);" as in controller?

Comment: Yes it is also shown above in show.blade.php

Comment: I would avoid using queries in template...not such a good ideea

Answer (score 2):

With Eager loading, "dot" notation loads **nested** relations.
In your controller you do

`Food::with('restaurant.categories')`

..this queries the `restaurant()` relation on the Food model, and that Restaurant's `categories()` relation.
I think you might need to call

`Food::with('restaurant', 'categories')`

as this will query both relations on the Food model.

Comment: I tried before this one.Can we use foreach same way as shown in show.blade.php?it gives me error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in show.blade.php

Comment: It could be that the 'categories' property is not visible for your Model. Try `dd($food->categories);` in your Controller, right before your return statement and see what it returns.

Comment: So there's your problem. Check if:
1. your Food model has correct settings for `$visible` or `$hidden` property
2. your Food model's table has a `food_categories` column that contains the foreign key (**I think this might be the problem, this seems like a weird column name to me**)
3. the foreign keys are set up correctly in your database/migrations